# convert the JSON string to a JavaScript object then create a HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, json

I need some help with JSON string operating.
The thing I want to do is convert the JSON string to a JavaScript object and make the HTML file look like below.
The first thing I do was use ***var obj = JSON.parse ( jsonstring );*** to put JSON string to JavaScript object.
After that, I wish to use for loop to traverse all the attributes in the JavaScript object then use the
value to create the table.
However, I fail to acquire the name of ***vote,name,race*** and ***gender*** etc. instead of its value by using ***.name***.
Loop control malfunctioning as well. ***.length*** always return something undefine error.
I will be grateful for any help you can provide.
Looking forward to hearing from you.

**Which Character Is The Best?**

**Characters: StarWarsCharacters**

**Record No.: 2**

**Senses:**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUIBw.jpg)

---

| vote     | name             | race  | gender |

---

| 34411224 | Obi-Wan Kenobi   | Human | Male   |

---

| 34458794 | Anakin Skywalker | Human | Male   |

---

enter code here

```js
var obj = JSON.parse ( jsonstring );
var labelsName = obj.labels[0];
var sensesName = obj.senses[0];

createTable(obj)

function createTable(obj) {

  var table = document.createElement("table");

          table.setAttribute("width","100%");

          table.setAttribute("border","1");

          table.borderColor="#FFFFFF";

          table.cellSpacing="0";

          table.cellpadding="0";

          table.borderColorDark="#FFFFFF";

          table.borderColorLight="#AAAAAA";

          parentTd = document.getElementById("parentTd");

          //console.log("    parentTd=", parentTd);

          parentTd.appendChild(table);

          var header = table.createTHead();

          header.bgColor="#EEEEEE";

          var headerrow = header.insertRow(0);

          headerrow.height="27";

  var labels = var.getElementsByTagName("labels");
  var senses = var.getElementsByTagName("senses");

for( var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++ ) {
  var rowObj = obj[i];
    for( var key in rowObj){
      console.log("    key =: ", key);
      console.log("    rowObj[key] =: ", rowObj[key]);
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
  
  <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">

  <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
  <body>

    <h1>Which Character Is The Best?</h1>
    <div valign="top" id="parentTd">&nbsp;</div>
    <script>


var jsonstring = ' { "labels": [ ' +
'{ "Characters": "StarWarsCharacters", "Record No.": 2, '+ 
'  "Senses": [ { "vote": 34411224, "name": "Obi-Wan Kenobi", "race": "Human",  "gender": "Male"},  ' +
' { "vote": 34458794, "name": "Anakin Skywalker", "race": "Human", "gender": "Male"} ]  } ] }'

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: so many errors in this script... `var.getElementsByTagName` (var is a keyword, you should use `document`), `obj.senses[0]` there is no field `senses` in the json... and the field `Senses` is not a property of the root object, `obj.length` is `undefined`, because obj is not an array... USE the JavaScript Debug console of your browser, it will show such errors!!! see: http://ggnome.com/wiki/Using_The_Browser_Error_Console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what you can do :

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.labels.length; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < json.labels[i].Senses.length; j++){
        document.getElementById('table').innerHTML += 
               '<tr><td>' + json.labels[i].Senses[j].gender + 
               '</td><td>' + json.labels[i].Senses[j].name + 
               '</td><td>' + json.labels[i].Senses[j].race + 
               '</td><td>'+ json.labels[i].Senses[j].vote + 
               '</td></tr>';   
   }    
}
```

Maybe you can try adding the headers dynamically using :

```
console.log(Object.keys(json.labels[0].Senses[0]));
```

which returns an array :

```
[ "vote", "name", "race", "gender" ]
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3e9Lu6u1/1/)